# How to retrieve the modelling function in statsmodels, Python?

Tags: python, static-methods, statsmodels

I am going to try to fit a model to my data.
I've read a little about Statsmodels in Python here: 
http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/example_formulas.html

but I haven't found anything about the function `f` used to model the data:
`f(X) = Y`.

A lot of parameters appear when we print `res.summary()`, but the only thing it says about the actual model is:

```
Model:  OLS 
Method: Least Squares
```

Can I somehow retrieve the function?

Comment: What "function" for the model do you want to retrieve? Can you be more specific. There is some formula information available, but the actual code for the model is spread over several classes.

Comment: I mean the function which takes the x_data and returns the modelled values for y. For example coefficients in linear regression.

Comment: The code for it is in model.predict, e.g. OLS.predict, which is just `exog.dot(res.params)` in the linear case. There is no string representation with the actual names.